# php -S not working (development server on LMDE with Firefox)

Tags: firefox, php, localhost

PHP 5.4 comes with a built-in development webserver:

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

When I try to start the server like documented everything looks fine:

> php -S localhost:3000
>
> PHP 5.4.4-2 Development Server started at Sat Dec 29 10:56:43 2012
>
> Listening on  localhost:3000
> Document root is /var/www
>
> Press Ctrl-C to quit.

When I curl localhost:3000 it works.

But It does not work with Firefox 17. The browser message is simple that it cannot connect to the website. Firebug shows the status "aborted" in the network console.

Is this a known issue? Can I change this behavior or at least debug it?

Comment: Hello madflow, There is the debugging solution for the php development server that I found. http://bit.ly/2M4kPvw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :D

http://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/771916

```
Type about:config into the address bar
Ignore the warning
Enter network.dns.disableIPv6 into the filter box
Right-click on the entry and press on toggle (it should now say false)
Close and restart FireFox
```